# How can I read only the first word of each line in a file in Java?

Tags: java

I have a file and it contains name, surname and age information. For example: Mike, Tyson, 54. There is 1 person in every 1 row. I just want to read the names. How can I do that?  I did the reading of all lines, but I could not only read the name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("C:/Users/muham/Desktop/students.txt");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        
        String s = reader.readLine();
        String[] students = new String[6];
        
        
        int i=0;
        while(s != null){
            students[i] = s;
            s=reader.readLine(); 
            i++;
        }
        Arrays.sort(students);
        String[] arr = null;
        for(i = 0; i<students.length;i++){
            System.out.println(students[i]);
        }
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What exactly isi the "*first word*", i.e. what is the separator between words?

Comment: There is a comma between each word. By the first word I mean the first word of each line.Like;
Mike,Tyson,54
Muhammet,Balıkçı,23 (they are on different lines)

Comment: Read the whole line, [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) on `","`. If the resulting array has a `length > 0`, access index `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split to get the name try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("C:/Users/muham/Desktop/students.txt");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        
        String s = reader.readLine();
        String[] students = new String[6];
        
        
        int i=0;
        while(s != null){
            students[i] = s.split(",")[0];
            s=reader.readLine(); 
            i++;
        }
        //Arrays.sort(students);
        String[] arr = null;
        for(i = 0; i<students.length;i++){
            System.out.println(students[i]);
        }
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }   
}
```

Comment: Oh. I didn't know how to use [0] after the split statement. Thank you so much.